# Local version of the fixed point theorem - Suli and Mayers (Page 11)

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

I am self-learning numerical analysis from the text Introduction to Numerical analysis, by Suli and Mayers. On page 11, the authors prove a local version of the contraction mapping theorem. The first couple of steps of the proof are not clear to me. Would someone be able to help explain, how he arrives at these steps.

> Theorem. Suppose that $g$ is a real-valued function, defined and continuous on a bounded closed interval $[a,b]$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Let $\xi = g(\xi) \in [a,b]$ be a fixed point of $g$ (whose existence is ensured by Theorem 1.2) and assume that $g$ has a continuous derivative in some neighbourhood of $\xi$ with $|g'(\xi)|<1$. Then, the recursive sequence $(x_k)$ defined by $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$, $k \geq 0$, converges to $\xi$ as $k \to \infty$ provided that $x_0$ is sufficiently close to $\xi$.

***Proof.***

Let $\xi \in (a,b)$. By hypothesis, there exists $h>0$, such that $g'$ is continuous in the interval $[\xi - h, \xi + h]$.

*Since, $|g'(\xi)| < 1$, we can find a smaller interval $I_\delta = [\xi - \delta,\xi+\delta]$, where $0<\delta\le h$, such that $|g'(x)|\le L$ in this interval, with $L < 1$.*

I really don't understand what theorem or corollary has been used to arrive at the above assertion.

Comment: What does Theorem 1.2 say, because $g(x)=x+1$ has no fixed points on any interval?

Comment: Theorem 1.2 is just the condition for the existence of a fixed point. If $g$ is continuous function over a closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$, such that $g(x) \in [a,b]$, then $g$ has a fixed point $\xi \in (a,b)$ such that $g(\xi) = \xi$.

Comment: Yes, I thought a hypothesis had to be missing (that the range of $g$ lives in $[a,b]$).

Comment: @Randall, that step is clear to me. What I fail to understand is the step in italics.

Comment: That is just using the continuity of the derivative. If $|g'(\xi)|<L<1$, then the set $\{x:|g'(x)|<L\}$ contains (or is) an open neighborhood of $\xi$. Or said differently, the set is open and contains $\xi$.

Comment: To paraphrase, what you said, as $g'(x)$ is continuous at $\xi$, for all sequences $(x_n) \to \xi$, $|g'(x_n)| \to |g'(\xi)|$. Since, the limit point $|g'(\xi)| < L$, there exists a $\delta$-neighbourhood around $\xi$, such that the terms of the image sequence $|g'(x_n)|$ must eventually settle in some neighbourhood of $|g'(\xi)|$, such that $|g'(x_n)|<L$. Is that correct?